# How to get the static value from dropdownlist and pass to database OnSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlist. In first dropdownlist have to pass only static values as mentioned below.Based on first dropdownlist value the second dropdownlist should automatically list corresponding values. After that Gridview should load.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged">
<asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Test1">Test1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="Test3">Test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Need to get value from static dropdownlist and pass to another dropdownlist

Comment: you want the whole code ? Have you done any effort ?

Comment: @Viswa: My previous comment contains a link :)

Comment: @Waqar: I have tried out using sqldatasource for dropdownlist it worked but need to know how to proceed with static dropdownlist

Comment: @Viswa Plz make your question clear and what do you mean by Static Dropdownlist ? Your question is not understandable.

Comment: In static we will be passing the value from the aspx page and get that value in C# page and pass it to another dropdownlist.( This can be done using sqldatasource too i.e we can get the list from the database for the dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. Create an event handler for first dropdownlist
   Example:

   ```
   Private void DDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
       // Here you bind your second dropdownlist 
   }
   ```
2. Then in the second dropdownlist event handler, Let it's name is DDL2

   ```
   Private void DDL2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
   {
      // Here you bind your Grid View
     // Put your logic here
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you. You have any link for static dropdownlist template

Comment: If my answer helped you, then mark it as your answer and what do you mean by Static DropdownList ?

Comment: There is only 1 answer to your question which I posted and it is visible to everyone, you have to follow those steps, if I clearly understand your query.

Comment: Since you are the person who asked the question you see a checkmark next to each answer to your question. Click the checkmark to accept a question.